Generic reponse model fastapi
What I am trying to do is to standardize my responses in my routes
For example:
ErrorDescription = TypeVar("ErrorDescription")

class PydanticBaseModel(BaseModel):
    """
    Base model for RequestsBody/Responses
    """

    model_config = ConfigDict(
        alias_generator=alias_generators.to_camel,
        populate_by_name=True,
        from_attributes=True,
        arbitrary_types_allowed=True,
    )

class BadResponse(
    PydanticBaseModel,
    Generic[ErrorDescription]
):
    status_code: conint(ge=400, le=499)
    error: ErrorDescription

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, *, status_code: int, error: ErrorDescription):
        return cls(status_code=status_code, error=error)

And then use it like so:
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("tmp")
def tmp(
):
    return BadResponse.new(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, error="Not found")

But of course the real response status will be 200. Is there any way to do that both statuses will be the same?


I can't seem to understand your question. You want all responses to be 200?

@drum desired behavior is when in response body status_code is X, real status also has X

Please update your question so that is clearer. Also include the actual and expected responses. I should be able to reproduce your problem locally given all your information.

The only way to do that is by raising HTTPException

The most flexible way is probably to use a custom Response that is aware of your specific rule for changing the status code:
class JSONStatusCodeAwareResponse(JSONResponse):
    def render(self, content: Any) -> bytes:
        # be aware that if you have a key named `status_code` somewhere else in your
        # application and return it as a base level key, this will override that as well.
        # - but since the Pydantic object has already been converted to a dict here,
        #   we'll work with what we have. This also works for a future GoodResponse.
        if isinstance(content, dict) and 'status_code' in content:
            self.status_code = content['status_code']
            
        return super().render(content=content)
        
 
@app.get("/foo", response_class=JSONStatusCodeAwareResponse)
def foo():
    return BadResponse.new(status_code=404, error="Not found")

If you want to use this as the default on all your endpoints, you can configure it on your FastAPI app object, so that unless it gets overridden explicitly, your response class gets used:
app = FastAPI(default_response_class=JSONStatusCodeAwareResponse)

This is also valid on an APIRouter instance, if you want to use it for a specific part of your application.
